# Trying to get code to update database column total by 3

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on code that updates points for someone when they contribute content. I have a table "points" and a column "contributions." When I create a variable called contributions and assign it a value of `3` and then do `SET contributions = $contributions` such as this below code it WORKS:

```
$contributions = 3
$yesupdate = "UPDATE points SET contributions = $contributions WHERE ID =  
$user_ID";
$stmt2 = $dbh->prepare($yesupdate);
$stmt2->bindParam(':WID', $yes_WID, PDO::PARAM_INT);        
$stmt2->bindParam(':approved', $e = Y, PDO::PARAM_STR);   
$stmt2->bindParam(':position', $row2[0]['position'], PDO::PARAM_INT);                                        
$stmt2->execute();
```

HOWEVER, I do not want the points to be set to 3. I want it to add 3 each time. So I tried the below approach, but nothing happens:

```
$yesupdate = "UPDATE points SET contributions = $contributions + 3 WHERE ID
= $user_ID";
$stmt2 = $dbh->prepare($yesupdate);
$stmt2->bindParam(':WID', $yes_WID, PDO::PARAM_INT);        
$stmt2->bindParam(':approved', $e = Y, PDO::PARAM_STR);   
$stmt2->bindParam(':position', $row2[0]['position'], PDO::PARAM_INT);                                        
$stmt2->execute();
```

Can anyone see what I am missing? Do I need to set the `$contributions` variable in example 2 like I did in example 1? If so, what would I assign to that variable when I just want the code to update the existing value of "contributions" in the database by 3?

Comment: I am surprised your first portion works. You maybe made a typo but you need a `;` after `$contributions = 3` first line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want your query to reference the current value in the column (not the variable) and add three:

```
UPDATE points SET contributions = contributions + 3 WHERE ID = $user_ID
```

You should use the prepare properly though too, have a look at: [PHP Manual: PDO::prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php)

Comment: That was it! needed to change $contributions to contributions without the $. And yes, I will clean up PDO...was just trying to get the nuts and bolts to work first. I assume it should like this:     $yesupdate = "UPDATE points SET contributions = :contributions + 3 WHERE ID = :ID;
$stmt2 = $dbh->prepare($yesupdate);
$stmt2->bindParam(':WID', $contributions, PDO::PARAM_INT); 
$stmt->bindParam(':ID', $user_ID, PDO::PARAM_INT);

Answer (score 0):

```
$yesupdate = "UPDATE points SET contributions = contributions + 3 WHERE ID = $user_ID";
$stmt2 = $dbh->prepare($yesupdate);
$stmt2->bindParam(':WID', $yes_WID, PDO::PARAM_INT);        
$stmt2->bindParam(':approved', $e = Y, PDO::PARAM_STR);   
$stmt2->bindParam(':position', $row2[0]['position'], PDO::PARAM_INT);                                        
$stmt2->execute();
```